# Installing pandas on python 3.6 (64 bit) is getting failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip

I am using python 3.6(64 bit) and want to install pandas using pip by the following command.

```
  pip install pandas
```

Error i got is:

```
    Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAIL
ED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)': /packages/07/54/5379878cd2ccabd
08ab9ce356e204a5bb46c870f203c93c808c22dd63125/pandas-0.23.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64
.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=
'files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/07
/54/5379878cd2ccabd08ab9ce356e204a5bb46c870f203c93c808c22dd63125/pandas-0.23.3-c
p36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIF
Y_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))
```

I tried another way by using trusted host

```
py -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org pip pandas
```

Error i got is :

```
      HTTP error 403 while getting https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/54/537
9878cd2ccabd08ab9ce356e204a5bb46c870f203c93c808c22dd63125/pandas-0.23.3-cp36-cp3
6m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=cbb074efb2a5e4956b261a670bfc2126b0ccfbf5b96b6ed021bc8c8c
b56cf4a8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!
=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*)
  Could not install requirement pandas from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packa
ges/07/54/5379878cd2ccabd08ab9ce356e204a5bb46c870f203c93c808c22dd63125/pandas-0.
23.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=cbb074efb2a5e4956b261a670bfc2126b0ccfbf5b96
b6ed021bc8c8cb56cf4a8 because of error 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http
s://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/54/5379878cd2ccabd08ab9ce356e204a5bb46c87
0f203c93c808c22dd63125/pandas-0.23.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Could not install requirement pandas from https://files.pythonhosted.org/package
s/07/54/5379878cd2ccabd08ab9ce356e204a5bb46c870f203c93c808c22dd63125/pandas-0.23
.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=cbb074efb2a5e4956b261a670bfc2126b0ccfbf5b96b6
ed021bc8c8cb56cf4a8 because of HTTP error 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: h
ttps://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/54/5379878cd2ccabd08ab9ce356e204a5bb46
c870f203c93c808c22dd63125/pandas-0.23.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl for URL https:/
/files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/54/5379878cd2ccabd08ab9ce356e204a5bb46c870f2
03c93c808c22dd63125/pandas-0.23.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=cbb074efb2a5e4
956b261a670bfc2126b0ccfbf5b96b6ed021bc8c8cb56cf4a8 (from https://pypi.org/simple
/pandas/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Note: Pip version is 10.0.1

Comment: `pypi.python.org` hasn't been the main index host since 2016, so you're following outdated information. And a few months ago, it went away entirely, so now that outdated information doesn't do any good. Notice that the errors are showing you the index URL (https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) and file URL (http
s://files.pythonhosted.org/…) in the error messages.

Comment: Anyway, you _should_ be able to use `--trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org` (as in the accepted anwser on the linked duplicate) just to upgrade `pip` and `setuptools`—and then, after that, everything else should install without errors. If not, there might be more to do, but try that first.

Comment: Also, if you're behind a corporate web proxy or anything like that, that could be a whole other problem—there are answers on the same question that cover that case as well, but it can be hard to figure out which one you need. (On the other hand, if you're behind a corporate web proxy, you ought to have corporate IT to help…)

Comment: I tried using pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pandas command and it gave same HTTP error 403

Comment: iam behind corporate proxy, that is causing this issue because im able to download the file on my mobile. I will talk to our IT and will resolve this issue. Thanks @abarnert for your insights